# using two consecutive values from a list in each iteration

Tags: python

I have posted a part of my code below. Newton() function calls Bezier() function. The Bezier() function has a list from where I get p0 and p3. What I am trying to do is, in 1st iteration the program should take the first and second items from the plist as p0 and p3. Then in 2nd iteration, p0 and p3 are the second and third items and so on. With each iteration, the p0 and p3 values should change. It's like the new p0 is the old p3. I could not put this in the code properly. Thank you.

```
import math

w = 1.0

def Newton(poly):
    """ Returns a root of the polynomial"""
    x = 0.5  # initial guess value
    counter = 0
    epsilon = 0.000000000001
    poly_diff = poly_differentiate(poly)

    while True:
        x_n = x - (float(poly_substitute(poly, x)) / float(poly_substitute(poly_diff, x)))
        counter += 1
        if abs(x_n - x) < epsilon :
            break
        x = x_n
        print "\tIteration " , counter , " : ", x_n

    print "u: ", x_n
    Bezier(x_n)

def Bezier(x_n) :
    """ Calculating sampling points using rational bezier curve equation"""
    u = x_n
    plist = [0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8, 0.6, 1.0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9] # list of parameter values of the phonemes

    for i in range(len(plist) - 1) :
        p0 = plist[i]
        p3 = plist[i + 1] 
        p1 = p0
        p2 = p3
        print p0, p3   
        p_u = math.pow(1 - u, 3) * p0 + 3 * u * math.pow(1 - u, 2) * p1 \
            + 3 * (1 - u) * math.pow(u, 2) * p2 + math.pow(u, 3) * p3
        p_u = p_u * w
        d = math.pow(1 - u, 3) * w + 3 * u * w * math.pow(1 - u, 2) + 3 * (1 - u) * w * math.pow(u, 2) + math.pow(u, 3) * w
        p_u = p_u / d

    print "p(u): ", p_u
    return plist

if __name__ == "__main__" :
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the top of your `Bezier` function to look like

```
def Bezier(x_n, p0, p3) :
    """ Calculating sampling points using rational bezier curve equation"""
    u = x_n
    p1 = p0
    p2 = p3
```

getting rid of that loop and the `plist` completely.

Then, in your `time` function (from my answer to your previous question [getting a boundary of an item from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070526/getting-a-boundary-of-an-item-from-another-list)), change it to look like:

```
def time() :
    tlist = [0.0, 0.12, 0.16, 0.2, 0.31, 0.34, 0.38, 0.46, 0.51] # list of start time for the phonemes
    plist = [0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8, 0.6, 1.0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9] # list of parameter values of the phonemes

    total_frames = math.floor(tlist[-1] / 0.04)
    t_u = 0.0
    i = 0
    while i < len(tlist) - 1:
        # if the number is in the range
        # do the calculations and move to the next number
        if t_u > tlist[i] and t_u < tlist[i + 1] :
            print "\n The t_u value:", t_u, 'is between',
            print "start:", tlist[i], " and end: ", tlist[i+1]
            poly = poly_coeff(tlist[i], tlist[i + 1], t_u)
            Newton(poly, plist[i], plist[i+1])
            t_u = t_u + 0.04 # regular time interval

        # if the number is at the lower boundary of the range no need of calculation as u = 0
        elif t_u == tlist[i] :
            print "\n The t_u value:", t_u, 'is on the boundary of',
            print "start:", tlist[i], " and end: ", tlist[i+1]
            print "u : 0"
            Bezier(0, plist[i], plist[i+1])
            t_u = t_u + 0.04 # regular time interval

        # if the number is at the upper boundary of the range no need of calculation as u = 1
        elif t_u == tlist[i + 1] :
            print "\n The t_u value:", t_u, 'is on the boundary of',
            print "start:", tlist[i], " and end: ", tlist[i+1]
            print " u : 1"
            Bezier(1, plist[i], plist[i+1])
            t_u = t_u + 0.04 # regular time interval

        # if the number isn't in the range, move to the next range
        else :
            i += 1
```

The only changes are putting the `plist` there and passing the `plist` values to `Newton` and `Bezier`.

The only changes to you `Newton` function are to change the first line to

```
def Newton(poly, p0, p3):
```

and the last line to

```
    Bezier(x_n, p0, p3)
```

Comment: I would add extra variable `td = 0.04` (*timedelta*), so there's a bit less repetition ;)

Comment: I changed things as little as possible to get them working. The question asker is having a hard enough time without me introducing another abstraction, just look at their question history.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> p = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for p1, p2 in zip(p, p[1:]):
...     print p1, p2
... 
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Does it help?

Comment: I guess my code is similar. When I embed this in my code it gives the same output like the one I have now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the `pairwise` iterator from [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) will help?

```
from itertools import izip, tee
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Comment: @ lazyr yes this helps but I want to to it in a simple way.  I don't understand itertools properly. I'm sure there is a simple way out. Thanks

Comment: @cvani: Using `itertools` is essential for idiomatic python. It's not that hard to understand either.

Comment: `itertools.tee` takes an iterator and returns *two* iterators, that can be in different positions in the underlying base iterator.  `next` just advances an iterator to the next position (and in this case, the iterated value is discarded).  `itertools.izip` is just like `zip`, it yields tuples containing a value from each iterator in its arguments.  (the difference is that izip iterates over its arguments on demand, but zip builds a list all at once and returns the whole thing, which is better depends on the inputs, but izip won't ever gulp up all of the system memory.)

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm you are actually asking for is called **sliding window** which was present in itertools recipes, a while ago:

```
from itertools import islice

def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result    
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result
```

Answer (score 1):

A generator would probably be my way of choice on this one, they're simple, easy, and can be wrapped up and modularized better than an embedded for loop

```
>>> def solution_pairs(list):
...     for p0, p3 in zip(list, list[1:]):
...         yield (p0, p3)
```

This can then be used in your code sussinctly in the for loop

```
>>> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for p0, p3 in solution_pairs(list):
...     print p0, p3
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

You could even wrap your entire for loop that you currently have into a generator and have it yield p_u if you were so inclined.

Comment: @ Jeff I understood this but I am not able to embed this in my code. If I do either it generates 10 p_u vales taking all the pairs in each iteration or 1 p_u value taking the last pair from the list. But it should be like each time Bezier() is called only one pair is taken giving out one p_u value. Thanks

Comment: @cvani So each time Bezier() is called it should be progressing the the loop by 1? If that's the case, why use a for loop, have Bezier be the generator or iterable item, and call its `__next__` manually from the calling module.